# Best way of closing custom React dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, listener

I know two ways of closing dropdown:

1. Listen for clicks and if target is not dropdown - close it.
2. Create transparent backdrop, with onClick event that will close dropdown.

I want to know which one of them is better in terms of performance? Something tells me that it should be second option, since we don't constantly listen for clicks. But everywhere I look in online examples, first option is mostly used, which made me curious in reason behind it?

This is not a question for opinion, but rather I'm interested in performance and possible issues of each method.

Comment: Performance of a single click handler is negligible. Add the event listener when the dropdown is opened, and remove it when the dropdown is closed.

Comment: In that case is it more efficient to create eventlistener once or create when dropdown is opened and remove when it's closed? On one side we have 1 event being set, but it will listen to clicks even if dropdown is not used. On the other side we will be registering and removing events constantly.

Comment: Personally, I'd just register the listener when the dropdown is rendered and not worry about adding/removing it only if it's opened. To "visualize" the performance, imagine having a table of data (maybe 100 rows) where the last column is an edit/delete button --  each of those buttons has a click handler. Adding one more to handle a dropdown "outside" click isn't going to impact perf.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to listen to click events on window object and toggle the a state variable. It's more simpler than creating a transparent backdrop.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
const outsideClick = useCallback((e) => {
    if (active) {
      setActive(false);
    }
  });

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", outsideClick);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", outsideClick);
    };
  });
```

In case there are situations, like a complex dropdown where sometimes clicking inside the drop container we don't want to hide the menu, you can do some additional checks like, inside the click handler -

```
e.target !== selectCategory.current.children[0]
```

Some examples on codesandbox - [#1](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-dropdown-select-demo-tlrmkv?file=/src/Dropdown.js), [#2](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-dropdown-forked-dlitrh?file=/src/Category.js:430-477)